# The drop down items are moved to right instead of present in same line

Tags: javascript, servicenow

[image]`

Home

Self Service

- My Issues
- Get Help
- Self Help

Contact Us

`

As shown above the drop down items should be aligned vertically. But I can not select 'Get Help' and 'Self help'. The drop down disappears If I try to move my cursor.

Comment: Please add more information like code. Reformat your question. Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found out that adding two elements fixed this.

z-index: 9999
position: relative

Added these to **li:hover ul**  style